# find the distribution of sum of a multinomial distribution

Tags: distributions, random-variable, multinomial-distribution

(**Background:** I am researching a economics problem and for the research, I need to know the general theory of multinomial distribution problems. This question is just an example to understand the general problems)

There is a fair dice. Let's say $X$ is the number you get when you roll the dice. $Y$ is the payoff we get according to $X$.

If $X=1 , Y=3$,

if $X=2$ or 3, $Y=1$,

if $X=4$ or 5, $Y=-1$,

if $X=6, Y=-3$,

Let $S_n$ be the sum of $Y$ for rolling the dice $n$ times.

When $X$ is i.i.d. random variable, what is distribution of $S_n$?

Comment: Consider the observable values of Y and the probability of getting them when throwing a fair die?

Comment: pr(Y=3)=1/6, pr(Y=1)=1/3,  pr(Y=-1)=1/3, pr(Y=-3)=1/6

Answer (score 1):

$$
f(Y)=
\begin{cases}
{1 \over 6},  Y=3\\
{1 \over 3},  Y=1\\
{1 \over 3},  Y=-1\\
{1 \over 6},  Y=-3\\
\end{cases}
$$

Let $Y_i $ be the payoff Y at the i-th rolling.

Then its moment generating function is:

\begin{align}M_{Y_i}(t) &= E(e^{tY_i})\\
&= e^{3t} {1 \over 6} + e^t {1 \over 3} + e^{-t}{1 \over 3}+e^{-3t} {1 \over 6}\end{align}

Hence,
\begin{align}M_{S_n}(t) &= E(e^{tS_n})=E[e^{t(Y_1 + Y_2 + ...+ Y_n)} \\&=\prod_{i=1}^n E[e^{tY_i}]\\ &= \prod_{i=1}^n \left( e^{3t} {1 \over 6} + e^t {1 \over 3} + e^{-t}{1 \over 3}+e^{-3t} {1 \over 6}\right)\\ &={1 \over 6^n}( e^{3t}  + 2e^t  + 2e^{-t}+e^{-3t})^n\end{align}

By multinomial theorem,
$$(a_1 + a_2  + a_3 + a_4)^n
 = \sum_{k_1+k_2+k_3+k_4=n; \ k_1, k_2, k_3, k_4 \geq 0} {n \choose k_1, k_2, k_3, k_4}a_1^{k_1}a_2^{k_2}a_3^{k_3}a_4^{k_4}$$

$$M_{S_n}(t) ={1\over 6^n}\sum_{k_1+k_2+k_3+k_4=n; \ k_1, k_2, k_3, k_4 \geq 0} {n \choose k_1, k_2, k_3, k_4} (e^{3t})^{k_1}(2e^{t})^{k_2}(2e^{-t})^{k_3}(e^{-3t})^{k_4}  \\
 ={1\over 6^n}\sum_{k_1+k_2+k_3+k_4=n; \ k_1, k_2, k_3, k_4 \geq 0} {n \choose k_1, k_2, k_3, k_4} 2^{(k_2+k_3)} e^{(3k_1+k2-k3-3k_4)t}$$

Therefore, the probability distribution
$$f(S_n=s_n)={1\over 6^n}\sum_{k_1,k_2,k_3,k_4}{n \choose k_1, k_2, k_3, k_4}2^{k_2+k_3}$$

where $\sum_{i=1}^4 k_i =n$, $k_i\geq 0$,$3k_1+k_2-k_3-3k_4 =s_n.$

Comment: Isn't the use of the moment generating function a very large detour to arrive at $$f(S_n = s_n) = \sum_{\forall 3k_1 + k_2 - k_3 -3k_4 \text{ and } k_i \geq 0} P(K_1=k_1,K_2=k_2,K_3=k_3,K_4=k_4)$$ and write $P(K_1=k_1,K_2=k_2,K_3=k_3,K_4=k_4)$ as the multinomial distribution $$P(K_1=k_1,K_2=k_2,K_3=k_3,K_4=k_4) = \frac{n!}{k_1!k_2!k_3!k_4!} p_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}p_3^{k_3}p_4^{k_4}$$

Answer (score 1):

- A general solution will be a convolution repeated several times, and this becomes difficult to compute for larger problems.
- An approximation can be made by approximating the sum with a normal distribution. Then you match the mean and variance $$P(S_n \leq s_n) \approx \Phi\left(\frac{s_n - \mu}{\sqrt{n}\sigma}\right) $$ where $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are the mean and standard deviation of your variable $X$.
- A specific solution, for your case, can be made by realizing that $X$ is a sum of two discrete uniform variables $X = 2(U+V)-3$ with $$P(U=0) = P(U=1) = P(U=2) = 1/3 \\ P(V = 0) = P(V=1) = 1/2$$ And the problem of rolling the 6-sided dice $n$ times can be seen as equivalent to drawing $n$ times the variable $U$ and $n$ times the variable $V$.

  The distribution of the sum of $n$ variables $V$ is a binomial distribution $$P(V_n = v) = {n \choose v} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n$$

  The distribution of the sum of $n$ variables $U$ is a discrete variant of the Erwin Hall distribution and in the case of a 3-dided dice it is:

  $$P(U_n = u) = \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^n\sum_{s=0}^{\lfloor u/4 \rfloor} (-1)^s {n \choose s} {u-4s+n-1 \choose n-1}$$

  (More general case is described in [How to express $(1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^m)^n$ as a power series?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28802/how-to-express-1xx2-cdotsxmn-as-a-power-series))

  And the sum of $V_n$ and $U_n$ can be described as a convolution $$\begin{array}{}P(S_n = s) &=& P\left(V_n + U_n = r =\frac{s + 3n}{2}  \right) \\& =& \sum_{u=0}^r P(U_n = k) \cdot P(V_n = n-k)\\& =& \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^n  \sum_{s=0}^{r-u} \sum_{s=0}^{\lfloor u/4 \rfloor} (-1)^s {n \choose s} {u-4s+n-1 \choose n-1} {n \choose n-u}\end{array}  $$

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Can you provide me a reference for the approximation with a normal distribution?

Comment: @martian03 here is the case for a sum of Bernoulli distributed variables, the [de Moivre–Laplace theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%E2%80%93Laplace_theorem). For a sum of discrete uniform distributed variables, it approaches a normal distribution by the central limit theorem, and more rigorously one would use the [Berry-Esseen theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry%E2%80%93Esseen_theorem) to show that it converges quickly to a normal distribution.