# Relationship between the distribution of weighted sum of a multinomial distribution and other well-known distributions

Tags: probability, random-variable, multinomial-distribution, discrete-distributions

Following is the explanation of multinomial distribution from a source of [lecture notes](http://faculty.washington.edu/yenchic/20A_stat512/Lec7_Multinomial.pdf) (by Yen-Chi Chen).

> The multinomial distribution is a common distribution for
> characterizing categorical variables. Suppose a random variable $Z$
> has $k$ categories, we can code each category as an integer, leading
> to $Z \in\{1,2, \cdots, k\}$. Suppose that $P(Z=k)=p_k$. The parameter
> $\left\{p_1, \cdots, p_k\right\}$ describes the entire distribution of
> $k$ (with the constraint that $\sum_j p_j=1$ ). Suppose we generate
> $Z_1, \cdots, Z_n$ IID from the above distributions and let
> $$ X_j=\sum_{i=1}^n I\left(Z_i=j\right)=\# \text { of observations in the
> category } j . $$
> Then the random vector $X=\left(X_1, \cdots, X_k\right)$ is said to be from a multinomial distribution with
> parameter $\left(n, p_1, \cdots, p_k\right)$. We often write $$ X \sim
>  M_k\left(n ; p_1, \cdots, p_k\right) $$ to denote a multinomial
> distribution.
>
> The PMF of a multinomial distribution has a simple closed-form. If $X
>  \sim M_k\left(n ; p_1, \cdots, p_k\right)$, then $$
>  p(X=x)=p\left(X_1=x_1, \cdots, X_k=x_k\right)=\frac{n !}{x_{1} ! x_{2}
>  ! \cdots x_{k} !} p_1^{x_1} \cdots p_k^{x_k} $$ The multinomial
> coefficient $\frac{n !}{x_{1} ! x_{2} ! \cdots x_{k}
>  !}=\left(\begin{array}{c}n \\ x_1, \cdots, x_n\end{array}\right)$ is
> the number of possible ways to put $n$ balls into $k$ boxes.

Now, let $Sn$ be the sum of weighted $X$. It means,
$$ S_n = \sum_{i=1}^k w_i X_i .$$

Then the Probability mass function of $Sn$ woule be following.

$$p(S_n =s_n)=\sum_{x_1,x_2,...,x_n} \left(\begin{array}{c}n \\ x_1, \cdots, x_n\end{array}\right) \Pi_{i=1}^k p_i^{x_i}   $$

where $\sum_{i=1}^k x_i= n $ ,$\sum_{i=1}^k w_i x_i = s_n $

(proof is here: [find the distribution of sum of a multinomial distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/598501/find-the-distribution-of-sum-of-a-multinomial-distribution/598592#598592))

**My question** is to find well-known continuous distributions which are related this distribution of $S_n$.  Well-know continuous distributions would be, for example, Normal distribution or Beta or Gamma or Dirichlet distribution. I guess that the above PMF will go to a Normal distribution when $n$ goes to infinity. Also, I guess that we can obtain the value of PMF $p(S_n=s_n)$ directly from a well-know continuous distribution with parameters instead of the above algorithmic equation.  I am looking for some reference for this question. However it is not easy to get the correct reference for this question.

Comment: This question is vague: What kind of relation are you seeking?

Comment: There are at least two questions. One is that, if n goes to infinity, binomial distribution goes to a Normal distribution. Is this same for multinomial distribution? Second question is , can I obtain the value of of () or () directly from a well-know continuous distribution with parameters instead of computing the above algorithmic equation (which uses x_i and combinations)?